# Camera Emulator "facing" acting strange

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-camera

running this in the debugger i see that info.facing == 0.  That means it is a back facing camera.

When i try to instantiate Camrea object i get null.

on the emulator i set the device to be backfacing camrea disabled and frontfacing camera enabled.  why does the device think there is a backfacing camrea when there isnt?

I am using Eclipse ADT.

here is my method.  I never reach the second loop. getCamreaInstance is returning c which is null.

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;

        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK){

            //Calling Camera.open() throws an exception if the camera is already in use by another application, so we wrap it in a try block.
            //Failing to check for exceptions if the camera is in use or does not exist will cause your application to be shut down by the system.
            try {
                c = Camera.open();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
            }
            return c;
        }
        //we want the back facing, if we cant get that then we try and get the front facing
        else if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
            c = Camera.open(Camera.getNumberOfCameras()-1); //i should test and see if -1 is a valid value in the case that a device has no camera
            return c;
        }
        else{
            //there are no cameras, so we need to account for that since 'c' will be null
            return c;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
```

does *not* get the current camera configuration. It's just an empty default constructor. The only way to get an accurate CameraInfo object is [Camera#getCameraInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getCameraInfo%28int,%20android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo%29).

The reason you're getting a null Camera is because the default `facing` is 0. So, it enters the first block, tries to `open()` which returns null because:

> If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null.

You can just call `getNumberOfCameras()` from the start to see how many cameras there are. Then open one and check it's `CameraInfo` to see which way it's facing.

However, if you always want the back-facing camera by default(which seems likely, given your code), just remove the checks to `facing` and check for null on `open()`.

Comment: excuse my ignorance.  What does the # in java do?
also is getCameraInfo a valid method with empty parameters? it looks like it here in the api docs but not in my ide... 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#Camera.CameraInfo()

Comment: Sorry, the `#` is just notation to refer to a method. It's a static method, and no, there is no option with no parameters. To save typing the parameters, I linked to the documentation for the method so you could see it yourself. The empty constructor shows up in the docs because by definition, all Objects have an empty constructor. It doesn't *do* anything, though.

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks for clearing that up.
you were right on with this answer

Comment: Also, my camera works while stepping through the debugger, but only displays black if i run in the emulator without the debugger. any thoughts?